# I want to access values from a popup back to the activity from which the popup has been called

Tags: java, android, popup

I've an Activity where I've a button which will lead to popup popup window in the same Activity. In that popup, I've multiple fields. And What I all want is to get back those values from popup to the same activity.

I've been stuck with it. Need a help :)

Related Code as follows.
This is the code in onCreate method for calling the popup.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           addProductDetails();
        }
    });
```

By calling **addProductDetails()** method popup gets displayed.

So in this method, the code as follows

```
private String addProductDetails() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.storeproductdetails_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element1), false);
    final PopupWindow pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

    //get txt view from "layout" which will be added into popup window
    //before it you tried to find view in activity container

    /* Field Data */
    product1Code = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.productCodeee);
    quantity1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.quantityy);
    details1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editText23);
    orderValue1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.editText36);

    productC = String.valueOf(product1Code.getText());
    qty = String.valueOf(quantity1.getText());
    dts = String.valueOf(details1.getText());
    orderVal = String.valueOf(orderValue1.getText());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    sb.append(productC+","+qty+","+dts+","+orderVal);

    System.out.println("StringBuffer Value: "+sb.toString());
    /* End of the field Data */
    Button doneAddingProduct = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.doneAddingProduct);

    //init your button
    Button btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.closePopup);
    btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pwindo.dismiss();
        }
    });

    doneAddingProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Inside onclick of done adding");

       Product product = new Product();
            product.setProductCode(productC);
            product.setQuantity(qty);
            product.setDetails(dts);
            product.setOrderValue(orderVal);
            app.setProduct(product);
            Intent intent = new Intent(OrderReturnMgmtSecondActivity.this, OrderReturnMgmtSecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //show popup window after you have done initialization of views
    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Here I was trying to do is two methods in fetching those field data back to the activity.
1) Simply trying to return the field data by concatenating as a string to who ever calls this method.

2)  Creating a pojo By the name as Product(which contains the field data) and setting it in application class i.e **MyApplication extends Application** ( you see that code as **app.setProduct(product)**) and redirecting it to the same activity and trying to fetch the data from that application.

But still I'm not able to get those field data.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: how you setting data in Application ?

Comment: I'm Configuring my custom application class in manifest file. So that the data in the application class will be visible in entire application. And I can use it anywhere or any Activity if required.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface

```
interface Listener {  
  void onResult(Product product);  
}
```

Pass a listener to the method and call it

```
addProductDetails(Listener listener){  
//...  
//when finished:  
listener.onResult(product);  
//...  
}
```

The caller now has to implement the interface

```
addProductDetails(new Listener(){  
  void onResult(Product product){  
    //do something with product 
  }  
});
```